# During a visit or on a visit

Tags: prepositions

Which phrase is correct or are they both correct? "I bought this ring during my visit to France". "I bought this ring on my visit to France".

Comment: "During" sounds better (to me at least).  "On" can mean on top of - it has other meanings while "during" is more specific.

Comment: @dardeshna - I agree that _during_ sounds better, but not because _on_ means "on top of" – _on_ means [so much more than that](http://www.onelook.com/?w=on&ls=a). For example, there's nothing incorrect about: _I went on a trip to France, and bought this ring while I was there_.

Comment: I think that 'on' is more likely than 'during' in informal: speech.  [Ross in Friends: "We were on a BREAK!"]

Answer (score 2):

Both forms are equally functional; the second case is the result of "while on" being simplified to just "on", similar to how "if you think that puppies are cute..." can be condensed into "if you think puppies are cute...".

Answer (score 0):

To me, 'during' sounds better, because it refers to the time (while I was there).

Here's an example for 'on my visit':

On my next visit to France, I will certainly visit you.

Answer (score 0):

"I bought this ring on my recent visit to France",
"I bought this ring last year whilst visiting France".
"When in France last year I bought this ring".
These are merely suggestions on how to say it differently, I do not particularly like the word "during", no reason really, just don't like the way to reads.